# How can I use array itemes for identifiers of deserialized json RootObject in c#?

Tags: c#, json

```
public class Rating
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Rated { get; set; }
    public string Released { get; set; }
    public string Runtime { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Writer { get; set; }
    public string Actors { get; set; }
    public string Plot { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Awards { get; set; }
    public string Poster { get; set; }
    public List<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
    public string Metascore { get; set; }
    public string imdbRating { get; set; }
    public string imdbVotes { get; set; }
    public string imdbID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string DVD { get; set; }
    public string BoxOffice { get; set; }
    public string Production { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
// JsonObject this is the c# class.cs file
public static string getJson()
        {
            string titleOfDesiredMovie = Console.ReadLine();
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string json = client.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + titleOfDesiredMovie + "&apikey=SECRETKEY");
            return json;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RootObject movie = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(getJson());
            string[] array = {
                                 "Title",
                                 "Year",
                                 "Rated",
                                 "Genre",
                                 "Writer",
                                 "Plot"
                             };
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length;i++ )
            { 
                foreach (var item in movie.array[i])
                {
                    Console.Write(item);
                }
            Console.WriteLine();
            }
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
        }
// the main file
```

I am using C# and I am developing a Console Application for getting info for certain movies using the OMDB API.
I am having problems when I enter array[i] for an identifier of the movie class. PS: this is my first question and if you have any feedback for improving it please let me know.

Comment: `movie` is a `RootObject` and it does not have a field named `array`.

Comment: What is inside the `json` object? A dump will be useful. I guess it returns a `List<RootObject>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want to output the values of some of the returned properties. Because you deserialized the JSON into a object, you would have to use reflection instead, or use `dynamic`.

A better solution for you would be to parse the JSON as `JObject` and then use indexing of this object:

```
JObject movie = JObject.Parse(getJson());
string[] array = {
                        "Title",
                        "Year",
                        "Rated",
                        "Genre",
                        "Writer",
                        "Plot"
                    };
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(movie[array[i]].ToString());
}
var key = Console.ReadKey();
```

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` library from NuGet.

If you rather want to use reflection, you would do the following:

```
RootObject movie = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(getJson());
string[] array = {
                        "Title",
                        "Year",
                        "Rated",
                        "Genre",
                        "Writer",
                        "Plot"
                    };
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    var propertyInfo = movie.GetType().GetProperty(array[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.GetValue(movie).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
var key = Console.ReadKey();
```